# Height of TextView is not increasing beyond screen height

Tags: android, textview

**Problem** : While adding text to a text view in android , when text is long enough to make textview height greater than screen, the textview is only increasing its height up to the screen height and not going beyond the screen.

**Requirement**: To increase the height of text view according to the text content .
Is it possible to change the height of a text view at runtime?

**EDIT**
Even though I change the height of TV (greater than height of screen) in XML
still my TV height is not exceeding screen height.

**EDIT 2**
I achieved this by drawing the TextView using canvas. I am not sure how efficient this is.

Comment: How could you see the part of the textView that is off the screen then? Why not enabling the scrolling?

Comment: Actually its an implementation of sticky header in recycler view but I am using an overlay of text view since I want customizable sticky header and some other requirements. Hence I can't use scrolling. But I am changing the y of text view according to the scroll of recycler view